# Macro to copy excel range of data as table to word goes outside margins

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write macro to copy table from excel to word. It should maintain formatting and must auto-fit to word. Table should not go out of range when pasted to word.

```
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

wdApp.Visible = True

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1:E36").Select
Selection.Copy

wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

Above code wors. It copies excel range of data as table to word. However table goes outside margins of word document.
Data in Excel - [image: Source Data in excel]
Data in Word after Copy - [image: After Copy to Word]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the end

```
wd.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False   'causing losing excel formatting
```

**Appended:**

```
'change fileformat and filename as per your need

wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
wd.SaveAs Filename:="demo.docm", FileFormat:=wdformatdocm
wd.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent 'you may try wdAutoFitWindow as well
```

Comment: It works..but losses all the formatting, colors etc.

Comment: See appended answer, it may serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
wd.Tables(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a bracket around wdAutoFitWindow