# Copy range from excel to word - set paragraph spacing to zero

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am trying to copy formatted ranges from excel to word. In order to do so, I use the code below ([Macro to copy excel range of data as table to word goes outside margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923745/macro-to-copy-excel-range-of-data-as-table-to-word-goes-outside-margins)). It works fine except for the line spacing. In excel I do not use line spacing (not controllable within a cell if I understand correctly). When I copy to word, everything works fine except for the line spacing which is set to 10 after a paragraph.

Thus, is there a way to control the line spacing (set it to zero) in the VBA macro that copies from excel to word with keeping all other excel formatting?

```
Sub ExportToWord()

Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

wdApp.Visible = True

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheetName").Range("table").Copy

wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False

End Sub
```

Comment: I added this after the paste command:

Dim wdTable As Table
Set wdTable = wd.Tables(wd.Tables.Count)
Debug.Print wdTable.Style.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing

Once you have the table object, you should be able to figure out how to modify its properties.

Comment: @Hrothgar, thank you. I should have thought about the word document being an object too. "wdTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0" allows me to set the linespacing.