# Copying multiple ranges from excel to word and controlling linespacing

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I manage to copy a range from excel to a newly opened WORD document and control the line spacing (thanks to some help [Copy range from excel to word - set paragraph spacing to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831011/copy-range-from-excel-to-word-set-paragraph-spacing-to-zero)).

However, I do not manage to control the linespacing when I copy multiple ranges to multiple bookmarks in an opened and existing word file (document.docx). The code can be found below at the end of the post.

This code works for an excel file with multiple sheets. One sheet is a configuration sheet. It contains the name of the excel sheet containing the table (in range "Name") and links this to the bookmark name in word (in range BookmarkExcel")".

I suppose the problem is with this piece of the code:

```
Set wdTable = myDoc.Tables(myDoc.Tables.Count)
wdTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
```

I tried all sorts of variations (e.g. replacing myDoc.Tables.Count by rep, 1, ...) but didn't manage to control the linespacing. What did I do wrong?

EDIT: **I found the cause**: the document contains already some tables (before and after the ones that I copy and paste) which causes the code for the line spacing not to work. Thus, how can I adapt my code such that it works for documents that already contain tables?

```
Sub ExcelTablesToWord()

Dim tbl             As Range
Dim WordApp         As Word.Application
Dim myDoc           As Word.Document
Dim WordTable       As Word.Table

Sheets("Configuration").Select
n = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set ListTables = Range("Name")
Set ListExcelBookmarks = Range("BookmarkExcel")


Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents("document.docx")

For rep = 2 To n

        SheetName = ListTables.Cells(rep, 1).Value

        On Error Resume Next
        Set existing = Sheets(SheetName)
        existing.Select 'added this

        lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If ListExcelBookmarks.Cells(rep, 1).Value <> "" Then

        Set tbl = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, lastColumn))
        tbl.Copy

        myDoc.Bookmarks(ListExcelBookmarks.Cells(rep, 1).Value).Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=False

        Dim wdTable As Table

        Set wdTable = myDoc.Tables(myDoc.Tables.Count)
        wdTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

    End If
Next rep
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count the tables up to current bookmark and then add one to get the newly added table index

here's your code with what above and some other (hopefully) useful refactoring:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExcelTablesToWord()
    Dim WordApp             As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc               As Word.Document
    Dim wdTable As Table

    Dim rep                 As Long
    Dim ListTables          As Range
    Dim ListExcelBookmarks  As Range
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet
    Dim tabName             As String

    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents("document.docx")

    With Worksheets("Configuration")
        Set ListTables = .Range("Name")
        Set ListExcelBookmarks = .Range("BookmarkExcel")
    End With

    For rep = 2 To ListExcelBookmarks.Rows.Count  '<--| loop through bookmarks range, skipping first row
        If ListExcelBookmarks.Cells(rep, 1).Value <> "" Then
            tabName = ListTables.Cells(rep, 1).Value
            If GetSheet(tabName, ws) Then '<-- GetSheet() returns 'True' if a worksheet named after 'tabName' is found and sets 'ws' to it. Otherwise it returns 'False'
                ws.UsedRange.Copy
                With myDoc
                    .Bookmarks(tabName).Range.PasteExcelTable _
                                                                        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
                                                                        WordFormatting:=False, _
                                                                        RTF:=False
                    Set wdTable = .Tables(.Range(.Range.Start, .Bookmarks(tabName).Range.End).Tables.Count + 1) '<--| add one to the tables before current bookmark to get the newly added one right after it
                    wdTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next rep
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(shtName)
    GetSheet = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the code works fine provided I replace tabname in Bookmarks(tabName) by  something that refers to the bookmark. E.g. by bookName (bookName = ListExcelBookmarks.Cells(rep, 1).Value).